# Android:Condition run only when certain method is running

Tags: java, android, testing

Hi im doing unit testing in Android and i want to show in my test that the method i have created is running on a different thread. Now i know the code for this but i want this code to only be run once this method has started running. This is for a test so basically if the method is on a different thread it passes

```
public void testMethodIsRunningOnDifThread(){

if(method is running on the UI thread)
   fail();
   }
   else
   {
   success
   }

}



if(methodisrunning){

start testMethodIsRunningOnDifThread();

}
```

something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have String UI_THREAD in your activity. and then assign it as the name of your UI thread. After that in the function get the instance of your current thread and get its name. If the name of the current thread is equal to your UI_THREAD string , then it is the UI thread else its a different thread. Hope this answers your questions.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String UI_THREAD = "uithread"; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Thread thread = Thread.currentthread();
        thread.setName(UI_THREAD);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    //This method will return true if it runs on a different thread else will return false
    public boolean testMethodIsRunningOnDifThread(){
      Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
      if(thread.getName().equals(UI_THREAD))
        return false;
      }
      else{
        return true;
      } 
    }
```

}